# What is the most efficient way to generate a link in a Rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku, erb

My app generates a user's calendar with available slots for booking appointments.  It automatically detects a visitor's time zone and displays the users' availability in the visitor's time zone.

Since the detected time zone is used to render the display, fragment caching will not work.

The view generates 100+ links which can be selected by the visitor to book a time slot for an appointment.  Benchmarking shows that generating the links is the slowest part of the view - taking about **0.5ms per link**.

**What is the most efficient way to loop through ERB and generate hyperlinks?**

We started using HTML instead of the link_to Rails helper - this was 2x faster in development but less so in production - our conclusion was that Heroku must be optimizing these Rails helpers.

```
<a href="/<%= @profile.profile_url %>/
appointments_calendars/<%= @appointments_calendar.id %>/
booked_events/new?
timezone_name=<%= @timezone.name %>&amp;
event_slot_id=<%= event_id %>"
class="left-slot open-slot" rel="nofollow">
<%= timeslot.strftime("%l:%M%p") %></a>
```

where
**@profile.profile_url** is a String, **@appointments_calendar.id** is an Integer from activerecord objects. **@timezone.name** is a String. They do NOT change in the loop - that is, they are generated when the page renders and do not change.

**event_id** is an Integer and **timeslot** is a Time. They are different for each link in the loop.

I am wondering if there is an optimal way to generate this HTML link in Ruby/Rails based on how the string buffering works.

The loop is an Integer range that runs for each day,

```
(first_hour..last_hour).step(1.hour).each
```

Alternatively, is there a faster way to do this in Rails that doesn't rely on ERB?

Comment: How are you defining `event_id` and `timeslot` each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
# somewhere before the loop starts:
<% slug = "/#{@profile.profile_url}/appointments_calendars/#{@appointments_calendar.id}/booked_events/new?timezone_name=#{@timezone.name}&amp;event_slot_id=" %>
```

Then you could do

```
<a href="<%= slug + event_id %>" class="left-slot open-slot" rel="nofollow">
  <%= timeslot.strftime("%l:%M%p") %>
</a>
```

I don't know if that would be the bottleneck or not, though it would be more readable.  I suspect the long time for generating links may also be linked to however you're defining `event_id` and `timeslot`.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with that solution but didn't see an obvious performance gain.  I thought someone might have some lower-level knowledge on how Ruby/Rails work with strings to point me to the optimal pattern.  As stated above, event_id is an integer and timeslot is a Time.  event_id came from a hash.  I've been pouring over every line and can find nothing slower than this link.  Thanks again.

Comment: Using the code above, comment out only the `href` portion, benchmark it, then comment out only the `timeslot` portion, benchmark it, then comment out both at the same time and benchmark it.  That should give you an idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks. I did some optimizing today, unfortunately - as is usually the case - there was no "smoking gun".  Just a matter of going line-by-line through the code and looking for inefficiencies. But thank you, yours was the answer to my question.